# FacebookAuthorizationException: User logged in as different Facebook user

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I am putting together a simple Android activity which displays a Facebook PlacePicker. When the user selects a place from the list, it should post their selection to their wall. This should not require the login button; the app does not request permissions (`publish_actions` in this case) until they are needed.

My PlacePicker works just fine. All the places I expect are loaded, and selecting one triggers the appropriate function, but the `requestNewPublishPermissions()` call fails every time. The exception being thrown is:

> com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: User logged in as different Facebook user.

I have only been able to find 2 other discussions online that include this error message, and neither of them were of any help to me. I have logged out of the Facebook app, logged out of Facebook on my mobile browser, and still it throws the same exception.

What the heck is going on here?

**onCreate()**

```
Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: onCreate");
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
isShared = false;
setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkin);

initLocationManager();
initPlacePickerFragment(getSupportFragmentManager());

lifecycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
lifecycleHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: null session");
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
    }
    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(this);
    }
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    }
}

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    pendingPublishReauthorization = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
}
```

**publish()**

```
Log.d(TAG,"CheckIn: Publishing Check In");
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (session != null){

    // Check for publish permissions
    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    for (String s : permissions) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: permission: " + s);
    }
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) { // This is always false, and loops endlessly
        Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: Getting permissions");
        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;

        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        newPermissionsRequest.setCallback(new StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: newPermissionsRequest.call()");
                Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: " + state.toString());
                Log.e(TAG, "CheckIn: " + exception.toString());
            }
        });
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: Has permissions");
    }

    // Activity has never gotten this far

    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("name", "Some");
    postParams.putString("caption", "Update Caption");
    postParams.putString("description", "Checked in somewhere who cares");
    postParams.putString("link", "http://www.redrobin.com/");

    Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: All set!");
            isShared = false;
            CheckInActivity.this.isShared = false;

            JSONObject graphResponse = response
                    .getGraphObject()
                    .getInnerJSONObject();
            String postId = null;
            try {
                postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "CheckIn: JSON error " + e.getMessage());
            }
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(CheckInActivity.this, error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(CheckInActivity.this, postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    Log.d(TAG, "CheckIn: Making me/feed request");
    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}
```

**Output:**

> CheckIn: onCreate
>   CheckIn: initLocationManager
>   CheckIn: initPlacePickerFragment
>   CheckIn: onResume
>   CheckIn: Session state changed: OPENED
>   CheckIn: New Location Found
>   CheckIn: setupPickPlaceFragment
>   CheckIn: found place // A place was selected
>   CheckIn: doPostStory
>   CheckIn: session is either open or closed. sharing
>   CheckIn: Session state changed: CLOSED
>   CheckIn: Session state changed: OPENED
>   CheckIn: Publishing Check In
>   CheckIn: Getting permissions
>   CheckIn: onPause
>   CheckIn: onSaveInstanceState
>   CheckIn: onActivityResult
>   CheckIn: onResume
>   CheckIn: newPermissionsRequest.call()
>   CheckIn: OPENED
>   CheckIn: com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: User logged in as different Facebook user.
>   **At this point the output starts repeating endlessly either from "newPermissionsRequest.call()" or "Session state changed: OPENED. Publishing Check In."**

I didn't want to overload this post with code, but please let me know if there are any other functions that would be helpful to see here.

Comment: I just tried throwing this on a different device and now I'm getting a whole new set of errors. It doesn't even load the PlacePicker places any more:

`Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.`